# outlier detection for a grouped (clustered) data

Tags: r, outliers

I wanna find outliers and eliminate them in my data(named "df"):

```
> head(df)

  cluster machine.code age Good.Times repair.price
1       1     13010132  23      58.54    198170000
2       1     13010129  23     105.25    390847500
3       1     13010131  23      20.50     20701747
4       1     13010072  18      14.30     22340000
5       1     13010101  18      57.63     13220000
6       1     13010106  27      49.96    254450000
```

where my data has 65 clusters and I wanna run the outlier detection within each cluster separately,
I had used the code below for outlier detecting before for one cluster and it was fine:

```
library("ggstatsplot")
df<- read.csv("C:/Users/gadmin/Desktop/dataE.csv",header = TRUE)
  ggbetweenstats(df,cluster, repair.price , outlier.tagging = TRUE)
  Q <- quantile(df$repair.price, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = FALSE)
  iqr <- IQR(df$repair.price)
  up <-  Q[2]+1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
  low<- Q[1]-1.5*iqr # Lower Range
  eliminated<- subset(df, df$repair.price > (Q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & df$repair.price < (Q[2]+1.5*iqr))
  ggbetweenstats(eliminated, cluster, repair.price, outlier.tagging = TRUE)
```

now I wanna do the same thing for all 65 clusters using "for" something like this:

```
 for(i in 1:length(unique(df$cluster))) {
   ...   
    }
```

but I don't how? (I mean the part that after outlier detecting the first cluster, how should it be replaced(subset) and continue the process to another cluster)

Comment: "I wanna find outliers and eliminate them in my data" Outliers are just cases that have characteristics not explained by the information you have. What is it about them that makes them outliers? If there's a data entry error and there's absolutely no reason to trust that information, sure - remove them. But if their characteristics are accurate, you are doing a disservice removing them.

Comment: due to the data gathering procedure, it is highly probable that data outliers are really outliers and needed to be removed

Answer (score 0):

**Core question**

There are various ways to detect outliers. As for the core of your question, I understand it as "How do I subset the data so I can apply a `for`-loop to remove the outliers for each cluster?"

```
# maybe insert a column id that assigns an id (identical to the row number) to identify individual entries
df$id <- seq(1, nrow(df))
# make a list to store the outlier ids for each cluster
outlrs <- list()

# loop through the clusters
for(clust in unique(df$cluster)){
subset <- df[df$cluster == clust,]
outlrs[[clust]] <- [INSERT YOUR OUTLIER DETECTION FUNCTION HERE*]
}

# remove the outliers
outliers <- do.call(rbind, outlrs)
df <- df[-outliers, ]
```

`*` *the outlier detection function you use should ultimately output the id of the row containing the outlier. This part would have to be adapted to your method of outlier identification.*

I didn't test it since I have insufficient data. You could use e.g. `dput(df)` to output a version of your data you can copy and paste to make it accessible to people who want to test their proposed solutions.

**Edit: one (of many) alternative approaches**

Alternatively, you could apply the functions you included in your question on a subset of the data within the loop, store the cleaned-up output e.g. as a list and subsequently apply `do.call(rbind.data.frame, your_list)` to the list.

**Note**

As Phil pointed out, it is questionable whether outliers should be removed, especially when you're just applying a loop that "takes care of them". While we can provide the means by which "outliers" can be removed programmatically, the question whether you should actually remove those outliers in a given situation is another one (probably more adequate on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)). It should also be noted that there are many algorithms to determine which values differ "significantly" from the bulk of values and the border between "significant" and not significant is arbitrary.